# Navigation item doesn't show

Tags: ios, segue

What's happening is I have a modal segue to a new window.

Then on that window the nav text or button doesn't show!

Note: I am trying to create the to-do list application that apple released the tutorial for!

[These are images of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td7lp.jpg)

Let me know if I am missing any crucial information!

Also: I tried changing the segue to push and that output an error. The error is

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

Comment: Those screenshots are way too tiny.  Do you have a nav-controller segue to another nav-controller?

Comment: yeah I do! I don't know why they are like that to be honest. =/

Comment: They're not supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure! @nhgrif ! But that raises a question. After I delete navigation controller how do I reconnect the other to the next window? I have this picture here so you can see what I mean http://i.imgur.com/0uaT0xs.png

Comment: Hold ctrl, click on the navigation controller and drag to the view controller.  Choose "push".

Comment: I did that and the screen I get looks like this http://i.imgur.com/WRBaspV.png where the screen that has the to-do text input field is actually just a big black box with no navigation bar items.

Comment: Nevermind! I Got it! I had to create  a new navigation controller and change make a push segue from the previous window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported" is the hint. Check your storyboard, if you are really using a "modal" presentation of the new view controller, or if you are accidently using the "push" operation, wich will only work for common view controllers. Push may not work for Navigation Controllers.

Comment: When I do modal the text doesn't show up like in the pictures!

Comment: you will have to embed your modal view controller in a new navigation controller for the modal presentation. This leads the new controller to have the navigation bar added.